# rails active model serializer not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I am using the the GEM found here: https://rubygems.org/gems/active_model_serializers

I've created the serializer using rails g, added it to the controller where I return json but it is still returning everything and not the defined attributes - Any ideas?

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProductDetailsController < ApplicationController          
            def show
                @prod = ProductPrice.joins(:product, :retailer).select("*")
                render json: @prod, serializer: ProductDetailSerializer
            end 
        end
    end
end

class ProductDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either your query is wrong - I´m guessing that since you are defining a `show` method what you are looking for is something like this:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProductDetailsController < ApplicationController          
            def show
                @prod = ProductPrice.joins(:product, :retailer).find(params[:id])
                render json: @prod, serializer: ProductDetailSerializer
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

If you really intend to serialize an array of ProductPrice objects you need to [pass the `each_serializer` option](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#2-for-an-array-resource).

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProductDetailsController < ApplicationController          
            def show
                @prod = ProductPrice.joins(:product, :retailer).all
                render json: @prod, each_serializer: ProductDetailSerializer
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Don't do `.select('*')` in Rails. It is an anti-pattern. Rails will by default select all columns in a table.